# are there concrete string names of functions and variables in the memory?

Tags: process

In computer memory, are there some concrete name for all the functions, variables, or just addresses?For example, the computer runs a process, p_1, it includes function f_1,variable v_1, at the runtime, can we find these strings "p_1","f_1" and "v_1" in the memory? And how?Sounds difficult.

Comment: It depends...the function and variable names might be in the binaries being executed, but probably won't be in memory unless the binary is being run under a debugger.  Processes have a process ID, and also information like command line arguments which include the binary name; that is more likely to be in memory.

Comment: What language? Some languages keep names available, some do not.

Comment: for example c and java.